# Array, with if statement

Tags: android, arrays

So i am busy with a program where i have this array called `names` and in the array i have the following data:

```
public static String [] name = {"Products", "Customers","Calculators","Logout"};
public static String [] subName = {"140 wide Plain", "140 wide Pattern", "280 wide Running width", "280 wide plain drops","280 wide pattern drops"};
```

now the following code i am trying to implement an if statement:

```
  private List<TitleMenu> getList() {
      List<TitleMenu> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
          List<SubTitle> subTitles = new ArrayList<>();

          if (names.equals("Calculators")){
          for (int j = 0; j < subNames.length; j++) {
              SubTitle subTitle = new SubTitle(subNames[j]);
              subTitles.add(subTitle);
          }}
          TitleMenu model = new TitleMenu(names[i], subTitles, null);
          list.add(model);
      }
      return list;
  }
```

so i only want the second portion of my code to implement if the if statement is correct but i cant seem to get the if statement correct. I am coding in android studio so i dont know how my if statement needs to be

Comment: names[i].equals("Calculators"). you need to reference the index of the array which is fundamental across most languages

Comment: @aquaballin it worked, so you can post it as an answer if you like

Comment: I just did, glad to help. Good luck with your application development. You can mark the answer correct by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the indices of the array. Each index in an array is represented by a number that starts at base zero. This is an important and fundamental concept across many programming languages.

It also looks like your array's name is not `names` and is `name`.

So you could check to see if the name is `"Calculators"` by doing something like this:

```
if (name[i].equals("Calculators")) { ... }
```